# AWS codebuild: CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDIN is still 1 even build step failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-codepipeline

```
Step 65/154 : RUN  apt-get install -y python3-pip
 ---> Running in 29f078573813
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package python3-pip
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y python3-pip' returned a non-zero code: 100

[Container] 2022/04/20 02:31:18 Phase complete: BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2022/04/20 02:31:18 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2022/04/20 02:31:18 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2022/04/20 02:31:18 Running command echo check CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING $CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING
check CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING 1
```

As above build log, I am using the AWS code pipeline and I try to install python3-pip in the docker but failed. It returns code 100. But the `BUILD State` is still `SUCCEEDED`. And when I echo the value of `CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING` in the post_build step, its value is still 1 which means the building succeeded. I think the [CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html) should be set as 0 automatically. I want to exit if the `CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING` is not 1.
Could you please help me to figure out why the `CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING` is still 1 even the exit code is 100?

In case you want to check my `buildspec.yml`:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      docker: 18
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws --version
      - echo $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
      - eval $(aws ecr get-login --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --no-include-email)
      - REPOSITORY_URI=xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test-farget-ecr-t
      - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
      - IMAGE_TAG=${COMMIT_HASH:=latest}
      ############################
      # Pull the previous docker image
      - docker pull $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - |
        if [[ $NEED_BUILD == "yes" ]]
        then
            docker build --cache-from $REPOSITORY_URI:latest -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .
            docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI:latest $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
        fi
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo "check CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING $CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING"
      - bash -c "if [ "$CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING" == "0" ]; then exit 1; fi"
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker images...
      - |
        if [[ $NEED_BUILD == "yes" ]]
        then
            docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
            docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
        fi
      - echo Writing image definitions file...
      - printf '{"name":"fargate-test-api-ecr","ImageURI":"%s"}' $REPOSITORY_URI:latest > imageDetail.json
artifacts:
    files:  
      - imageDetail.json
      - taskdef.json
      - appspec.yaml
```

Comment: Please provide the whole script, there could be settings that result in this flow

Comment: @detzu I attached my `buildspec.yml`, plz review.

Comment: does the docker flow stop after the python error is it finishing ? don't use the --cache-from until you solve this issue, could trick you. Would be good to show the Dockerfile if possible

Comment: @detzu The docker flow stopped after the python error and the build stage stopped also. Then the post_build stage started. However, the log appears that `BUILD State: SUCCEEDED` which means the code pipeline doesn't raise the exit code 100 of the docker error.  I doubt the `--cache from` causes this issue. Before I use it, the code pipeline works as expected.

Comment: This is happening every time you try ?

Comment: @detzu yes, every time. Now I manually exit with exit code 100 to raise this error. Then the code pipeline appears failed and CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING was set as 0 automatically.

Comment: I've been having the same issue for some time: `docker build` fails, it logs `The command '...' returned a non-zero code: 2`, but then it continues executing the same stage as if nothing happened. Also, `CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING` is set to `1` on post-build

Answer (score 2):

CodeBuild only gets the exit code of the last command in each build step. In the buildstep

```bash
if [[ $NEED_BUILD == "yes" ]]
then
    docker build --cache-from $REPOSITORY_URI:latest -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .
    docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI:latest $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
fi
```

your last command is `docker tag` whose exit code is independent of the previous `docker build` command. You should combine these commands with `&&` to short circuit in the case of a failed `docker build`.

Comment: if [ $CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING -eq 0 ]

Answer (score 0):

had to add this image : [image]
?

Privileged mode is activated in codebuild?

Comment: yes, Privileged mode is activated already.